# tensorflow, access inner elements of a variable and freeze some of them

Tags: python, tensorflow

In a weight tensor, which is a matrix for suppose, how do I select some of the elements from the weight matrix and add it to a list of variables to be froze and rest of elements of matrix to be trained in tensorflow?
example: created a variable W: of size 20*20
how can I pick out few elements like W[0][1],W[13][15] and freeze them in optimizer

```
    ........
    def rnn_cell(rnn_input, state, weight):
           with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell', reuse=True):
               W = tf.get_variable('W', [n_inputs + n_neurons, n_neurons])
               b = tf.get_variable('b', [1, n_neurons], 
                     initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
            return (tf.tanh(tf.matmul(tf.concat([rnn_input, state], 1), weight) + b))


     part_W = tf.scatter_nd([[0,0]], [W[0][0]], [178,150])
     W_2 = part_W + tf.stop_gradient(-part_W + W)
     state = init_state
     rnn_outputs = []
     for rnn_input in rnn_inputs:
             state = rnn_cell(rnn_input, state, W_2)
             rnn_outputs.append(state)
     final_state = rnn_outputs[-1]

     logits = fully_connected(final_state, n_outputs, activation_fn=None)
     xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,
     logits=logits)
     loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
     optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
     training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
     correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
     accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
     init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

     with tf.Session() as sess:
              init.run()
              for epoch in range(n_epochs):
              for iteration in range(mnist.train.num_examples // 
      batch_size):
                            X_batch, y_batch = 
                mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                            X_batch = X_batch.reshape((-1, n_steps, 
                            n_inputs))
                            h=np.zeros([batch_size,n_neurons])
                            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: 
                            y_batch, p:h})
            acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch, 
            p:h})
            q=np.zeros([10000,n_neurons])
            acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, y: y_test,p:q})
            print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test 
            accuracy:",acc_test)
```

Comment: How are frozen variables chosen?

Comment: elements are chosen at random

Answer (score 0):

I would recombine the weights with a copy of it-self going through `tf.stop_gradient`. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10, 10)))
mask = tf.cast(tf.random_uniform((10, 10), 0, 2, dtype=tf.int32), tf.bool)
w = tf.where(mask, w, tf.stop_gradient(w))
```

Comment: how can I use tf.stop_gradient multiple number of times?I.e for each epoch if I want to freeze different elements, how do I use stop_gradient multiple times? I have tried several ways to use this function but none worked for me

Comment: In the example I gave the gradients are blocked for different elements each time.

Comment: did u try it? cause it doesnt work out that way i guess

Comment: I did, and it does. Post your code if you have any issue with it.

Comment: I have posted most of my code, so here while training in n_epochs, for each epoch I must freeze different variables, If you see in my code, I froze all variables of W except W[0][0] using stop_gradient.....but for next epoch, I need to freeze different variables. How can I do it? This code works perfectly fine(no errors)

Comment: Then you simply need `mask` to be a variable that is changed at each epoch.